# Can you explain the function of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, electromagnetic

I am interested in implementing the motor in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGa-9FpcB7o). I understand the whole process and the physics behind it, but I do not understand the function of [the circuit in the same video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGa-9FpcB7o&t=296s) as I have such basic knowledge in circuits.

Can anyone explain this circuit? Why did he use 1k, and 10k instead of 100k, and 1M for example, or 2, and 20? I mean, why did he chose these specific values? Same for the diode and the transistor.

If I am going to do the same exact circuit with the same components, do I have to do it on a PCB to sustain high currents?

I have a variable DC power supply (0-30V), up to 10A.

[image]

Comment: Please don't edit out information that is necessary to the question. Thanks.

Comment: The question has been released under a creative commons license. I would appreciate it if you would not deface the question. The question cannot stand on it's own without the refrence to the video and the image.

Comment: That is an interesting motor, made of a reed switch and magnets. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGa-9FpcB7o

Answer (score 5):

R1 is used as a "pull down" it ensures that Q1 blocks when you release the button.

R2 is here to build a resistor divider with R1 and sets the voltage that is applied to the gate of Q1 when you press the button. Without R2, the voltage at the gate of Q1 would be your max input voltage (30 V) and in the datasheet it's written that the transistor will die if that voltage exceed 20 V.

Why 10 kΩ and 10 Ω?

The voltage at the gate is given with the following formula:

\$U_{gate} = V1 \times \frac{R1}{R1 + R2}\$

There are an infinite number of combination that will work, but you have to take into account other constraints:

You have to choose values of R1 and R2 such that U_Gate is greater than the threshold voltage of Q1 (worst case 4V, given in the datasheet) and smaller that the max gate voltage of 20 V.

You also have to pick values small enough that Q1 turns on and off quickly to make sure it doesn't burn by staying too long is a region where it has to dissipate energy. Small R1 and R2 will ensure that this will happens quickly enough.

If you pick too small values, then, when you press the button, some current will flow through R1 in series with R2, and R1 and R2 have maximum dissipation capabilities.

The current the flow through R1 and R2 (it's the same) is given by:

\$I_{res} = \frac {V1}{R1 + R2}\$

Next you have to check that the power dissipated by R1 and R2 are not too large for the resistor you picked:

\$P_{r1} = R1 \times I_{res}^2\$

and

\$P_{r2} = R2 * I_{res}^2\$

\$P_{r1}\$ and \$P_{r2}\$ must be smaller that 0.25 W (for standard through hole 1/4 W resistors.)

Next the transistor. It is suited to your need, it can handle your 10 A continuously given proper cooling (the small black radiator fixed to the transistor.)

The diode can sustain up to 80 A in surges and 10 A continuous, thus it's ok.

You don't need a PCB. You can directly solder component together. It's ugly, not professional, but regarding your application it may be good enough.

What you should not use is a breadboard. It won't sustain your 10 A.

Comment: Directly soldering components together was called "christmas tree" and was accepted prototyping before breadboards became popular or hobbyists could afford breadboards. I am sure many on here used that method... Or they would make a "pcb" using simple wire connections.

Comment: @MkalmAbdlkem If you have follow-up questions please ask them as new question post(s).

Answer (score 2):

> I only do not understand the function of the circuit in the same video as I have so basic knowledge in circuits.

From my understanding, The motor has magnets attached to it so, when one of the magnets passes close to the reed relay, the mosfet conducts and so there is a electromagnetic  field due to the inductances. The magnetic field pushes the magnet up and so the next magnet triggers the reed end so on.
[image]

[image]

As you can see, When I first close the switch(in reality the reed relay) The voltage between the inductors and the transistor (drain) goes up , and then down. Up beacause at first the current is blocked (due to the [electromotive force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force)) and then down beacause is goes trough the diode. Then when I close the switch, the voltage goes down and showing that the current going trough the inductors thus having a electromagnetic field. Then the voltage stabilizes back to 12V.

> Why did he use 1k, and 10k instead of 100k, and 1M for example, or 2, and 20, I mean why did he chose these specific values? Same for the diode and the transistor.

The 10k resistor is actualy a pull-down resistor. This is a classic value.
The Schottky Diode has been choosen beacause it can handle big currents (like the transistor).

> do I have to do it on a PCB to sustain high currents?

Probably, most breadboard don't support that much current. You could try to find you that can too.

Comment: We're getting flags about the comments here having turned into a discussion, which is [not an allowed use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756). Comments should be used to clarify an answer, not to ask further questions. Therefore the comments have been moved to chat (see link below), where discussion (as long as it complies with the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct)) is allowed. || This bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, so any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141451/discussion-on-answer-by-matvic-can-you-explain-the-function-of-this-circuit).